# (4.1 -> 4.2) Attempted to load class TemplateComponent from namespace Joomla\Component\Administrator\Extension calling $app->getTemplate

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x, joomla-api

I have a file `test.php` that manually loads the Joomla framework and prints template parameters.

```
<?php
// test.php, located in the same directory that index.php is
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', '.');

require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php');
require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php');

$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');
$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);

\Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;

// Uncomment to mitigate the error:
// JLoader::registerNamespace('Joomla\Component\Templates\Administrator', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_templates/src');
$templateParams = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;// error (see explanation below)
var_dump($templateParams);
```

In Joomla 4.1, the call to `app->getTemplate(true)` works fine because [the function makes the database calls itself](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/71389ff3d73122359d3812abaa64f9928ab653cc/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php#L468).

In Joomla 4.2, the call to `app->getTemplate(true)` [delegates the database calls to the `com_templates` service provider](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/bd7a0b288f3262766e2b283c1e9dcd1960802aa5/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php#L477) (I'm not exactly sure how). But since the `Joomla\Component\Templates\Administrator\Extensions` namespace isn't loaded, we get a `ClassNotFoundError` for class `TemplatesComponent`.

Below is the stack trace:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError:
Attempted to load class "TemplatesComponent" from namespace "Joomla\Component\Templates\Administrator\Extension".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

  at /srv/http/administrator/components/com_templates/services/provider.php:47
  at Joomla\DI\ServiceProviderInterface@anonymous/srv/http/administrator/components/com_templates/services/provider.php:28$484->{closure}()
     (/srv/http/libraries/vendor/joomla/di/src/ContainerResource.php:182)
  at Joomla\DI\ContainerResource->getInstance()
     (/srv/http/libraries/vendor/joomla/di/src/Container.php:96)
  at Joomla\DI\Container->get()
     (/srv/http/libraries/src/Extension/ExtensionManagerTrait.php:174)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->loadExtension()
     (/srv/http/libraries/src/Extension/ExtensionManagerTrait.php:50)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->bootComponent()
     (/srv/http/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:442)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->getTemplate()
     (/srv/http/test.php:23)
```

If I add `$app->getTemplate(true)` to an `HtmlView::display()` function, it works just fine and a `var_dump` shows what I'd expect.

So I was wondering if I was initializing the Joomla framework wrong or something.

Comment: I had the same problem after updating from J4.1.0 to J4.2.0 and your post made me resolve the issue. Adding the 'JLoader::registerNamespace...' line did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Hm which `HtmlView::display` function did you change exactly?

Comment: Hm my error seems more related to the autoload_psr4.php file, and probably write permission confusion. I could copy it from another machine.

Comment: Came back to this, the precise file location is `administrator/cache/autoload_psr4.php`